# SELECT query with conditional joins, return all rows when no data in lowest join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm looking for a solution where a query should return:

a) a limited set of rows when there are rows in the lowest joined table

b) all rows if there is no data in the lowest joined table

c) taking into account that it is possible that there is more than 1 such join

**Objective**:

we are implementing security using data. Rows from the table (MainTable) are filtered on 1 or more columns. These columns have a relationship with other tables (LookupTable). Security is defined on the LookupTable.

*Example1*: the MainTable contains contact information. One of the columns holds the country code, this column has a relationship with a LookupTable that contains the country codes. The user can only select a country code that exists in the LookupTable. The security admin can then define that a user can only work with contacts of one or more countries. When that user accesses the MainTable he/she will only get the contacts of that limited list of countries.

*Example2*: the MainTable contains products. One column holds the country of origin code, another column the product group. Security setup can limit the access to the product MainTable of a user to a list of countries AND a list of product groups.

The security setup works by Management-by-Exception, whichs means that the MainTable is filtered when one or more "security filters" are defined but if no security filters are defined then the user will get ALL rows from MainTable. So my query should return a limited number of rows if any security filter is defined but should return all rows if there are no security filters defined.

**Current situation:**

I have been working on a query for the case of Example2. There are 4 possible scenarios:

1. No security filters are defined
   expected outcome: all rows are returned
2. Security filter defined only for first LookupTable
   expected outcome: only rows matching values between LookupTable1 and security filter are returned
3. Security filter defined only for second LookupTable
   expected outcome: only rows matching values between LookupTable2 and security filter are returned
4. Security filter defined only for both LookupTables
   expected outcome: only rows matching values between LookupTable1 AND LookupTable2 and security filter are returned

The query I have is correct for cases 2,3 and 4 but fails for case 1 where no rows are returned (as per my understanding this is due to the fact that both JOINS return an empty result set).

**Background:**

The application provides the (power) users with some kind of table designer which means that they can define which columns are linked to a LookupTable and which of these LookupTables can be used for the "security filters".

This means that, potentially, we could have a MainTable with for example 200 columns of which 20 are linked to a LookupTable which are defined as security filter. The queries are stored procedures which are generated when "design" changes are saved.

With the query I have now (working for 3 out 4 cases) the number of scenarios is equal to 2^N where N is the number of LookupTables. If N is 20 the total goes over 1 million.

Security setup is done with Profiles assigned to Users and Filter Sets assigned to Profiles and Filter Set Entries containing the actual values to filter on (if any).

The environment is currently on MS SQL 2017 but will be put into production on SQL on Azure.

Example of the query (but look further below for the link to dbfiddle):

```
SELECT E.col_pk, E.col_28, E.col_7, E.col_8, E.col_9, E.col_1052
FROM MainTable AS E
LEFT JOIN LookupTable2 AS L28 ON L28.col_pk = E.col_28
  JOIN SecUserProfile AS UP28 ON UP28.IdentityUserId = @UserId
    JOIN SecProfileFilterSets AS PFS28 ON PFS28.SecProfileId = UP28.SecProfileId
      LEFT JOIN SecFilterSetEntry AS SE28 ON SE28.SecFilterSetId = PFS28.SecFilterSetId AND SE28.MdxEntityId = 2 AND SE28.EntityKey = L28.col_pk
LEFT JOIN LookupTable13 AS L1052 ON L1052.col_pk = E.col_1052
  JOIN SecUserProfile AS UP1052 ON UP1052.IdentityUserId = @UserId
    JOIN SecProfileFilterSets AS PFS1052 ON PFS1052.SecProfileId = UP1052.SecProfileId
       LEFT JOIN SecFilterSetEntry AS SE1052 ON SE1052.SecFilterSetId = PFS1052.SecFilterSetId AND SE1052.MdxEntityId = 13 AND SE1052.EntityKey = L1052.col_pk
WHERE
(SE28.SecFilterSetId IS NOT NULL AND SE1052.SecFilterSetId IS NOT NULL)
OR
(
    SE28.SecFilterSetId IS NOT NULL AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 NUP1052.Id FROM SecUserProfile AS NUP1052
    JOIN SecProfileFilterSets AS NPFS1052 ON NPFS1052.SecProfileId = NUP1052.SecProfileId
       JOIN SecFilterSetEntry AS NSE1052 ON NSE1052.SecFilterSetId = NPFS1052.SecFilterSetId AND NSE1052.MdxEntityId = 13
    WHERE NUP1052.IdentityUserId = @UserId
    )
)
OR
(
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 NUP28.Id FROM SecUserProfile AS NUP28
    JOIN SecProfileFilterSets AS NPFS28 ON NPFS28.SecProfileId = NUP28.SecProfileId
       JOIN SecFilterSetEntry AS NSE28 ON NSE28.SecFilterSetId = NPFS28.SecFilterSetId AND NSE28.MdxEntityId = 2
    WHERE NUP28.IdentityUserId = @UserId
    )
    AND SE1052.SecFilterSetId IS NOT NULL
)
OR
(
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 NUP28.Id FROM SecUserProfile AS NUP28
    JOIN SecProfileFilterSets AS NPFS28 ON NPFS28.SecProfileId = NUP28.SecProfileId
       JOIN SecFilterSetEntry AS NSE28 ON NSE28.SecFilterSetId = NPFS28.SecFilterSetId AND NSE28.MdxEntityId = 2
    WHERE NUP28.IdentityUserId = @UserId
    )
    AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 NUP1052.Id FROM SecUserProfile AS NUP1052
    JOIN SecProfileFilterSets AS NPFS1052 ON NPFS1052.SecProfileId = NUP1052.SecProfileId
       JOIN SecFilterSetEntry AS NSE1052 ON NSE1052.SecFilterSetId = NPFS1052.SecFilterSetId AND NSE1052.MdxEntityId = 13
    WHERE NUP1052.IdentityUserId = @UserId
    )
)
```

**Issue:**

I have the following issues but they probably boil down to 1 in the end:

1. my current query is only 75% correct
2. even if my current query is correct it cannot be used in production with the potential high(er) number of lookup tables.
3. performance needs to be taken into account. Just as we don't know the number of columns and lookup tables at design time we don't know how many rows the tables will contain. The main table may hold 500, 50000 or 500000 records.

In the end all this will boil down to the right solution :)

I think this is not the easiest of questions (otherwise I will feel very stupid) and for those willing to take a look I've prepared a sandbox environment on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e09b387513708be36725350e390e813) representing the use-case I'm working with. I've setup the query to run 4 times, once for each of the scenarios.

Comment: Find the largest subexpressions that you can show are correct then ask a concise specific question about 1 of the the first place(s) you don't get what you expect. This is basic debugging. Extend that to a [mre], which is obligatory in a debugging question & should appear as text in your self-contained question along with a link to where you ran it.--Cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. (Clearly this query isn't minimal & its spec isn't clear.)

Comment: Well, the problem is that the query has no bug. Its result is correct looking at the grammar of the query. But it is not the behavior I'm looking for. That's why I took the time to make an elaborate description of the requirement and provided and actual, working use-case. @philipxy I didn't want this to be another 3-line question without background but something others might recognize as a hurdle they took in the past.

Comment: Seems there is a pattern where you could first get some rows where NOT EXISTS certain other rows & then get the rows in that (either empty or unfiltered) subquery result that match certain other rows (per JOIN). PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Even if you can't clearly/concisely/completely say what you want you can give DDL, example input initialization & example output.